# JAVA timing Bubblesort and Quicksort algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm

I am new to Java and trying to time my Bubblesort and quicksort algorithms to see which one is faster! I have done some research and know for timing your code in Java you can use System.currentTimeMillis(). Cant seem to get my System.currentTimeMillis() to work for timing bubble or quick, any help would be really appreciated.

```
// Class implementing an array based list.
// Bubblesort and quicksort algorithms are implemented also.

class ArrayList
{
private static int SIZE;    //size of the array that stores the list items
private int[] list;         //array to store the list items
private int length;     //amount of items in the list

// Default constructor
public ArrayList()
{
    SIZE = 20;
    list = new int[SIZE];
    length = 0;
}

// Three-Arg constructor
public ArrayList(int size)
{
    SIZE = size;
    list = new int[SIZE];
    length = 0;
}

// Determines whether the list is empty
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return length == 0;
}

// Prints the list elements
public void display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}

// Adds the element x to the end of the list. List length is increased by 1
public void add(int x)
{
    if (length == SIZE)
        System.out.println("Insertion Error: list is full");
    else
    {
        list[length] = x;
        length++;
    }
}

// Removes the element at the given location from the list.
public void removeAt(int pos)
{
    for (int i = pos; i < length - 1; i++)
        list[i] = list[i + 1];
    length--;
}


// Returns the number of items in the list (accessor method).
public int getLength()
{
    return length;
}

// Returns the size of the list (accessor method).
public int getSize()
{
    return SIZE;
}

// Removes all of the items from the list
public void clear()
{
    length = 0;
}

// Replaces the item in the list at the position specified by location
public void replace(int location, int item)
{
    if (location < 0 || location >= length)
        System.out.println("Error: invalid location");
    else
        list[location] = item;
}

// Adds an item to the list at the position specified by location
public void add(int location, int item)
{
    if (location < 0 || location >= length)
        System.out.println("Error: invalid position");
    else if (length == SIZE)
        System.out.println("Error: Array is full");
    else
    {
        for (int i = length; i > location; i--)
            list[ i] = list[ i - 1];
        list[location] = item;
        length++;
    }
}

public void remove(int item)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if (list[i] == item)
        {
            removeAt(i);
            i--;    //consecutive values won't be all removed; that's why i-- is here
        }
}

// Returns the element at location
public int get(int location)
{
    int x = -1;

    if (location < 0 || location >= length)
        System.out.println("Error: invalid location");
    else
        x = list[location];

    return x;
}

// The methods listed below are new additions to the ArrayList class

 // Makes a deep copy to another ArrayList object
public ArrayList copy()
{
    ArrayList newList = new ArrayList(this.SIZE);

    newList.length = this.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        newList.list[i] = this.list[i];

    return newList;
}

// Bubble-sorts this ArrayList
public void bubbleSort()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++)
            if (list[j] > list[j + 1])
            {
                //swap list[j] and list[j+1]
                int temp = list[j];
                list[j] = list[j + 1];
                list[j + 1] = temp;
            }
}

// Quick-sorts this ArrayList
public void quickSort()
{
    quickSort(0, length - 1);
}

// Recursive quicksort algorithm.
private void quickSort(int begin, int end)
{
    int temp;
    int pivot = findPivotLocation(begin, end);

    // swap list[pivot] and list[end]
    temp = list[pivot];
    list[pivot] = list[end];
    list[end] = temp;

    pivot = end;
    int i = begin;
    int j = end - 1;

    boolean iterationCompleted = false;
    while (!iterationCompleted)
    {
        while (list[i] < list[pivot])
            i++;
        while ((j >= 0) && (list[pivot] < list[j]))
            j--;

        if (i < j)
        {
            //swap list[i] and list[j]
            temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[j];
            list[j] = temp;

            i++;
            j--;
        } else
            iterationCompleted = true;
    }

    //swap list[i] and list[pivot]
    temp = list[i];
    list[i] = list[pivot];
    list[pivot] = temp;

    if (begin < i - 1)
        quickSort(begin, i - 1);
    if (i + 1 < end)
        quickSort(i + 1, end);
}

// Computes the pivot location
private int findPivotLocation(int b, int e)
{
    return (b + e) / 2;
}

}

// Class to test bubblesort and quicksort algorithms implemented in ArrayList
public class Lab4B
{

public Lab4B()
{
    //creating a list of integers
    int n = 25;
    ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList(n);

    //filling the list with random integers
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        numbers.add((int) (Math.random() * 100));

    //printing the list
    System.out.println("Original list of numbers:");
    numbers.display();

    //testing bubblesort
    ArrayList numbersCopy1 = numbers.copy();
    System.out.println("\nBubble-sorted list of numbers:");
    numbersCopy1.bubbleSort();
    numbersCopy1.display();

    //testing quicksort
    ArrayList numbersCopy2 = numbers.copy();
    System.out.println("\nQuick-sorted list of numbers:");
    numbersCopy2.quickSort();
    numbersCopy2.display();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Lab4B myAppl = new Lab4B();
}
```

HERE is my attempt:

```
//printing the list

    System.out.println("Original list of numbers:");

    numbers.display();

    Long[] bubblelist = new Long[10];

    Long[] quicklist = new Long[10];

    //testing bubblesort

    ArrayList numbersCopy1 = numbers.copy();

    System.out.println("\nBubble-sorted list of numbers:");

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    numbersCopy1.bubbleSort();

    long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();

    numbersCopy1.display();

    System.out.println("Time taken is : " + (finish - start));

    bubblelist[0]=finish - start;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        numbersCopy1.bubbleSort();

        finish = System.currentTimeMillis();

       finish = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }

    //testing quicksort

    ArrayList numbersCopy2 = numbers.copy();

    System.out.println("\nQuick-sorted list of numbers:");

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    numbersCopy2.quickSort();

    finish = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Time taken is : " + (finish - start));

    numbersCopy2.display();

    quicklist[0]=finish - start;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        numbersCopy2.quickSort();

        finish = System.currentTimeMillis();

        quicklist[i]=finish - start;

    }
```

Comment: I don't see a call to System.currentTimeMillis() anywhere in this code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to upload it. I have edited my post now!

Comment: @Chc So what doesn;t seem to work ?

Comment: I keep getting 0 for all my times.

Comment: @Chc Have you tried printing the values out to the console to see their value s?

Comment: Yes all Im getting is Null 0.

Comment: Please don't use `ArrayList`, or any other classname that appears in java.lang or java.util, as a name for your own classes. Other programmers will find it extremely confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With small sorting problems on modern computers, you should be done in far less than a millisecond.  Try using `System.nanoTime()` in Little Child's answer.

Comment: I shall give it a try!

Comment: Even using nanosecond precision is not going to yield reliable comparisons for such small input data.

Comment: Bubble-sorted list of numbers:
1 2 2 15 16 16 17 17 18 19 20 22 23 24 25 49 54 55 55 60 65 68 81 95 98 
Time taken is : 23000

Quick-sorted list of numbers:
Time taken is : 22000

Comment: Interesting results though. Shouldn't Bubble-sorting be faster?

Comment: @Alex Agreed, that the precision will be dubious.  However, if OP wants reliable timings for small amounts of data you can get reasonable estimates by looping around the problem.  Run the loop N times both with and without sorting, and the difference divided by N should be a good estimate of the time the sort requires.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `System.getTimeMillis()` once before you call your bubble sort method and once after you call it. Then, the difference between the two `System.getTimeMillis()` values is the time taken for bubble sort to complete.

```
long startTime = System.getTimeMillis();
bubbleSort(numberArray);
long endTime = System.getTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Time Taken = " + (endTime - startTime));
```

Comment: @Marcelo Sarcasm ? Or do you really mean it ? :-/

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, but I overreacted a little.

Comment: @Marcelo Please consider using emoticons frequently. They avoid a lot of confusion. =D

Answer (score 0):

Sorting an array of 25 longs, even with a slower algorithm like bubble-sort, will be extremely fast on any modern PC. It's likely that the method is completing fast enough that the CPU time before and after is the same.

To see any significant difference in execution times, you'll have to sort a larger array of input numbers.